# Showing this function is increasing or decreasing

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, monotone-functions

We have a function
$$f(x) = e^x - x\int_{0}^{1} z^n e^{-xz} dz$$ that is defined and continuous for all $x \in [-a, 0]$. We also know that $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to determine how $f(x)$ changes as $x$ varies in $[-a, 0]$ but I'm having a hard time with it.

I tried to show that $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ for $x_1 < x_2$ but it wasn't successful. I also tried to use some results in Karlin, S. 1968. Total Positivity. Vol. 1. Stanford University Press, but it was very complicated for me.

I need some guidance and any comments and hints are very appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to compute the derivative?

Comment: This is slightly peculiar, since $a$ is presumably arbitrary.

Comment: @blamethelag yes, if I'm not mistaken, by Leibniz integral rule, we have $\frac{df(x)}{dx}=e^x-\int_{0}^{1}z^ne^{-xz}dz+x\int_{0}^{1}z^{n+1}e^{-xz}dz$ but I'm not sure where to go from here!

Comment: @copper.hat that's correct, $a$ can be any real number.

Comment: The function seems to have a minimum at some $x_n^*\in(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$\int_{0}^{1} z^n e^{-xz}\, dz=x^{-(n+1)} (\Gamma (n+1)-\Gamma (n+1,x))$$
$$f(x)=e^x-x^{-n} (\Gamma (n+1)-\Gamma (n+1,x))$$

Expanding as series
$$\Gamma(n+1,x)=\Gamma(n+1)+x^n \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{ x^k}{(k-1)!\,\, (k+n)}$$
$$f(x)=e^x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{ x^k}{(k-1)!\,\, (k+n)}=\frac 1{e^{-x}}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ (-x)^k}{(k-1)!\,\, (k+n)}$$ and you consider the case where $x <0$. Letting $x=-y$, we have
$$g(y)=\frac 1{e^{y}}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{ y^k}{(k-1)!\,\, (k+n)}$$ where all terms are now positive for $0< y <a$.

I hope that this could help you.